# Get drupal data from some php file

Tags: php, drupal

I want to make "**php to image**" link that integrates with data from Drupal. Anyway to do this?

I want to give away image link to users in the system that will link back to get image from the site.

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/img_user.png?uid=788" />
```

and use .htaccess to rewrite to **img_user.php** which execute the code below to return the right png for requested uid.

```
** $user_class = A CODE FROM DRUPAL TO GET "field_user_class" FROM uid = 788 eg. RETURN "supporter" **
$imgpath = "/sites/all/themes/example/images/{$user_class}.png"
$type = 'image/png';
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($imgpath));
readfile($imgpath);
```

However, I can't find a way to execute the first line. And I can't user db_query since img_user.php is not a drupal template file. Could you point out any documents or post that explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. I just need to include bootstrap.inc then I can fully integrate with Drupal from any php files.

In my case img_user.php is on the root of the site:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
include('includes/bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
// Do anything..
```

Please add if there is any additional suggestion on what I am doing. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, that's the standard Drupal's bootstrap  code. Just add it at start of php file and you'll have all Drupal's functionality available.